# Adding int's from txt file to vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

Writing a program that reads a txt file, inputs the values into a vector, then determines the number of values (temperatures) that are below freezing. I keep getting 0 as the result and can't figure out what I have wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the actual assigned question and my code so far
Write a main program that asks the user for a file name. The file contains daily temperatures (integers).

The main calls the two functions to (1) store temperatures in the vector (2) display the number of days with freezing temperatures (<= 32o F).

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 //prototypes
 void readTemperaturesFromFile(vector<int>& V, ifstream&);
 int countFreezingTemperatures(vector<int>& V);


 int main()
{
ifstream ins;
string fileName;
int totalFreezing = 0;
vector<int> temperature;

cout << "Please enter the name of the file: ";
cin >> fileName;

ins.open(fileName.c_str());

readTemperaturesFromFile(temperature, ins);
totalFreezing = countFreezingTemperatures(temperature);

cout << "Total number of days with freezing temperature: " << totalFreezing << 
endl;



ins.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}

// The function reads temperatures (integers) from a text file and adds 
// pushes them to the vector. The number of integers in the file is 
// unknown
void readTemperaturesFromFile(vector<int> &V, ifstream& ins)
{
int temperature, v;
while (ins >> v)
{
    V.push_back(v);
}

}

// The function returns the number of freezing temperatures (<=32oF) 
// in the vector. 
// You need to consider the case where the vector is empty
int countFreezingTemperatures(vector<int>& V)
{
int counter = 0;
if (V.empty());
cout << "empty" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
    if (V[i] <= 32)
    {
        return counter;
        counter++;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Because you are returning immediately once a temperature is freezing before increasing the counter at all in `countFreezingTemperatures`. Also the semicolon after `if (V.empty());` does not belong there, it will cause the following line to be executed unconditionally. Learn to use a debugger to step through your program and find errors in the program logic.

Comment: Are you sure that opening a file succeeded? I see no tests for it

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any tips or sites that systematically teach how to get better at debugging or is it a skill that comes solely from experience?

Comment: I just checked and it's saying the file failed to open, any advice on that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `countFreezingTemperatures` function
There is unnecessary `;` after `if` 
You should count all the temperature `<=32oF` and then return the `counter`

```
int countFreezingTemperatures(vector<int>& V)
{
  int counter = 0;
  if (V.empty())
  {
     cout << "empty" << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
    {
       if (V[i] <= 32)
       {  
         counter++;
       }
     }
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *countFreezingTemperature* implementation is returning 0. Take a look:

```
for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
    if (V[i] <= 32)
    {
        return counter;
        counter++;
    }
 }
```

This code is saying "immediately upon reaching a temperature at/under 32, return counter" (which is set to 0).

Here's a fix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
    if (V[i] <= 32)
    {
        counter++;
    }
 }
return counter;
```